# How to get contents from Jodit text editor

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, jodit

I'm trying to get contents of Jodit editor into a variable.

I have tried looking through their documentation but nowhere can I find how to do it. I've had a look at their methods documentation but information provided there doesn't connect any dots.

```
    <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary ml-3" id="save">Save</button>

    <script>
        var editor = new Jodit('#editor', {

        });

        $('#save').on('click', function(e) {
             var text = editor.someMethodThatGetsContents(); 
             alert(text); 
        });
    </script>
```

I think I should get a html string.

Answer (score 4):

```
   var editor = new Jodit('#editor');
   var editor_val = editor.value;

   console.log(editor_val);
```

Try this way, maybe this going to help you.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I have also found editor.getEditorValue(); to work too.

Answer (score 1):

from the docs:

```
function handleContent(newValue) {
...
const x =  newValue.srcElement.innerHTML;
...
}

<JoditEditor
...
onBlur={handleContent}
...
/>
```